# how to pass only one argument with click in python?

Tags: python, arguments

I am new using [click package](https://pypi.org/user/mitsuhiko/). I have a function with two arguments and I want to pass only one of them using click, the argument `i` is passed inside of the statement if.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

@click.command()
@click.argument('filename')
def plot_graph(i, filename):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph_animated = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_graph, interval=1000)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the relevant code in a "command" function and use a closure over the `filename` variable:

```
import click
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


@click.command()
@click.argument('filename')
def main(filename):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    def plot_graph(i):
        # Closure over `filename` here.
        # Alternatively you can use additional kwarg `filename=filename`.

    graph_animated = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_graph, interval=1000)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```